# Angular + firebase to fcm Messaging and Token :Error Service Worker

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire

i have a webpage which has to get notifications using firebase so i added firebase to get the fcm meassaging token but i have some issue in the related to service worker which i never came up before

this is my firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/12.9.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/12.9.1/firebase-messaging.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "Myapikey",
    authDomain: "MyDomain",
    databaseURL: "myDatabseUrl",
    projectId: "my ProjectID",
    storageBucket: "My Storage",
    messagingSenderId: "MessagingId",
    appId: "AppId",
    measurementId: "Measure ID"
};

// Initialize Firebase
console.log("javascript works ===>>>>")
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

// Set up a message listener to receive messages in the background
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  // Customize how your app handles the background message
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

this is my Messagingservice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import firebase  from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase, ref, push,onChildAdded } from 'firebase/database';
import { getDownloadURL, getStorage, ref as StorageRef, uploadBytes } from 'firebase/storage'; // Correct import statement
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from "@angular/fire/compat/messaging";
import { environments } from '../Environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseServiceService {

  currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  private firebaseApp;
  private database;
  private storage;

  constructor(private angularfireMessaging :AngularFireMessaging) { 

    
    
    // this.firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(environments.firebase);
    this.firebaseApp = initializeApp(environments.firebase);
    this.database = getDatabase();
    this.storage = getStorage();

    
    
  }

  requestPermission(){
    
    this.angularfireMessaging.requestPermission.subscribe(
      (token)=>{

        console.log(token);
        this.angularfireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
          (token)=>{
            console.log(token);
            
          }
        )
        
      },(error)=>{
        console.log("unable to get permission"+ error);
        
      })
      
    }
    receivemessage(){
      this.angularfireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
        (payload)=>{
          console.log('New Message Recieved'+payload);
          
          this.currentMessage.next(payload);
        })
        
        
        
        
        
        
  }
```

```
on App.module.ts
```

```
imports: [
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireMessagingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environments.firebase),
```

```
//and i called it in the app.component.ts

 message: any
  
  constructor(private fireaseserv:FirebaseServiceService,private internetservice:InternetServiceService){}
  // loader = true;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  
    this.fireaseserv.requestPermission();
      this.fireaseserv.receivemessage();
      this.message = this.fireaseserv.currentMessage
    this.internetservice.getIsOnline().subscribe(isOnline=>{
      this.showPopup = !isOnline
    })


  }
```

but iam getting this error in my log

Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:4200/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:4200/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).

please Guide me through this
"how to generate the token using firebase cloud messaging ......"